# Sliding a UIView "Out of nowhere"

Tags: swift, user-interface, drop-down-menu, uiview

i am trying to create a custom dropdown menu. I will have several cards on my view which should have a dropdown menu when tapped.

Right now i am having the `dropDownView` having `cardView.frame.maxY` as its `frame.origin.y` value with a height of 0 and when I tap the card view I set the height of the `dropDownView` to its real height-value within an animation.

But that looks kind of ugly since it looks like it stretches out of nowhere. I want it to slide out of nowhere.

By that i mean it having its original size right away and sitting below the card view (`cardView.frame.maxY = dropDownView.frame.maxY`) When the cardView is tapped the `dropDownView` slides down (`dropDownView.frame.origin.y = cardView.frame.maxY`) within an animation.

The Problem is, that the `dropDownView` is bigger than the `cardView`. So when it sits behind the `cardView` it is visible above the `cardView`. I tried to illustrate the Problem :)

This is state A (Before View A[cardView] is tapped) (View C is just some Background View which should be visible above and below View A)

[image]

This is state B (after cardView is tapped)

[image]

Any Ideas how to solve this problem? Thank you!

In addition heres a little sample code:

```
class cardViewComplete: UIView {

    var card: CardView!
    var dropDownMenu: DropDownView!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    func initSubViews() {

        self.clipsToBounds = true

        card = CardView()
        card.frame = self.bounds
        card.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YellowTackleTicketComplete.ticketTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

        dropDownMenu = DropDownView()
        dropDownMenu.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: self.bounds.maxY, width: self.bounds.width, height: 350)
        dropDownMenu.hidden = true
        dropDownMenu.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        self.addSubview(card)
        self.insertSubview(dropDownMenu, belowSubview: card)
dropDownMenu)
}

    func showDropdown() {
        dropDownMenu.hidden = false
        originalHeight = self.frame.size.height
        print("showing")
        if !animating {
            animating = true
            UIView.animateWithDuration(
                0.7,
                delay: 0,
                usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
                initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                options: [],
                animations: {
                    self.frame.size.height = self.frame.size.height + 350
                }, completion: { _ in
                    self.animating = false
                }
            )
        }
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.dropDownMenu!.setNeedsDisplay()
        dropped = true
    }
    func ticketTapped() {

            showDropdown()
    }

}
```

Comment: You could just put the viewB behind viewC? so that it will be covered by it before ViewA is touched.

Comment: Hi Alberto, im sorry, i think my second drawing is a little bit irritating. View C isn't supposed to end at the bottom of view A. It is supposed to be the allover Background View. Right now i am experimenting with clipsToBounds = true. But till now i could not manage to get a smoot slide down/up animation with it.

Comment: I do not understand your problem I guess :/ ... so when you touch viewA you want viewB to swipe up? (if you set a view with clipsToBounds = true the subviews inside it will be not visible outside its bounds)

Comment: No, i want viewB to slide down, like a Dropdown Menu. View C is just the Background View. But its supposed to be a custom Background. I just integrated this into the example so that you know, that it is not an option do just put a white view (or something similar) above viewA to "block" viewB since this would block the custom backgroundView as well. Thank's already for your help!

Comment: so viewC contains viewB and viewA? can you post some code ? :)

Comment: Exactly. viewC is the ViewControllers view. ViewA and ViewB belong to a custom "Card with dropdown menu" View. I'm going to put several of those on the ViewController's view. I added sample code in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is place both View A and View B inside a new view, we can call this containerView.

containerView should be big enough to hold both A and B (when B is moved down). Then set containerView to clip at bounds. So when View B is in the "up" position, it is sitting both behind View A, and clipped at the top of containerView. Therefore it is not seen at all.

Once you're ready for View B to drop to it's "down" position, just animate it going down, where it will appear to come out from the bottom of View A. Since the containerView's frame will extend far enough down to accommodate A and B (in it's down position), nothing will be clipped and both views will be visible.

```
card = CardView()
card.frame = self.bounds
card.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YellowTackleTicketComplete.ticketTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

dropDownMenu = DropDownView()
// I changed the frame to place it right underneath the card view
dropDownMenu.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: card.frame.size.height - 350, width: self.bounds.width, height: 350)
dropDownMenu.hidden = true
dropDownMenu.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

let containerView = UIView()
containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: card.frame.size.height + dropDownMenu.frame.size.height)
containerView.backgroundColor = nil
containerView.clipsAtBounds = true
containerView.addSubview(dropDownMenu)
containerView.addSubview(card)
```